# If I click on increment or decrement of button it also changes the value of 1st div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
<div class='basket-card quantity' style = "align-content:center;">
     <button class="counter-button decrement-btn changeQuantity">-</button>
        <h3 class="rounded-button qty-input" id="qty">2</h3>
     <button class="counter-button increment-btn changeQuantity">+</button>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.increment-btn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var incre_value = $(this).parents('.basket-card').find('.qty-input').val();
            // var incre_value = document.getElementById('qty').innerHTML
            var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
            // var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
            // var price = document.getElementById('price').innerText;
            // var total = parseInt(value) * parseInt(price);
            // var total_price = document.getElementById('total_price').innerText;
            // var finalPrice = document.getElementById('price').innerText;
            // var final_price = parseInt(finalPrice)+parseInt(total)
            value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
            if(value<10){
                value++;
                $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
                $('#qty').html(parseInt(value))
                // $('#total_price').html(parseInt(final_price))
                // $('#amount').html(parseInt(final_price))
                
                // $('#total_price').html(parseInt(final_price))
            }

        });

        $('.decrement-btn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
            var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
            
            // var price = document.getElementById('price').innerText;
            // var total = parseInt(value) * parseInt(price);
            // var total_price = document.getElementById('total_price').innerText;
            // var finalPrice = document.getElementById('price').innerText;
            // var final_price = parseInt(finalPrice) - parseInt(total);
            value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
            if(value>1){
                value--;
                $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
                $('#qty').html(parseInt(value))
                // $('#total_price').html(parseInt(final_price))
                // $('#amount').html(final_price)
            }
        });
        $('.changeQuantity').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // var quantity = $(this).closest(".cartpage").find('.qty-input').val();
        // var product_id = $(this).closest(".cartpage").find('.product_id').val();
        // alert(quantity)
        // var data = {
        //  'quantity':quantity,
        //  'product_id':product_id,
        // };
        
    });

    });
    </script>
<script>
```

If I updates the value of 1st element then it is working, but if I click on another element increment or decrement it increases/decreases the value of 1st element  tag.

If there is any solution then kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `.qty-input` is a `h3` element. It does not have a `value` property to be read by `val()`. The first time you click one of the buttons it sets (invalidly) a `value` property on the element and then continues to work from there.

To fix this change `val()` to `text()` in all cases you deal with that element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.increment-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var incre_value = $(this).parents('.basket-card').find('.qty-input').text();
    var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
    
    if (value < 10) {
      value++;
      $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').text(value);
      $('#qty').html(parseInt(value))
    }
  });

  $('.decrement-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').text();
    var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value > 1) {
      value--;
      $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').text(value);
      $('#qty').html(parseInt(value))
    }
  });

  $('.changeQuantity').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='basket-card quantity' style="align-content:center;">
  <button class="counter-button decrement-btn changeQuantity">-</button>
  <h3 class="rounded-button qty-input" id="qty">2</h3>
  <button class="counter-button increment-btn changeQuantity">+</button>
</div>
```

Also note that the code can be made more succinct by combining the button event handlers and using a `data` attribute to control the increment value. You can also use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to control the extents the value can be set to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.counter-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let $button = $(this);
    let $qty = $button.parents('.basket-card').find('.qty-input');
    let value = parseInt($qty.text(), 10) || 1;    
    let change = $button.data('change');
    
    value += change;
    $qty.text(Math.max(Math.min(value, 10), 1));
  });

  $('.changeQuantity').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='basket-card quantity' style="align-content:center;">
  <button class="counter-button decrement-btn changeQuantity" data-change="-1">-</button>
  <h3 class="rounded-button qty-input" id="qty">2</h3>
  <button class="counter-button increment-btn changeQuantity" data-change="1">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just updated the answer with an improved version of the logic